# Unity world asset streaming

Tags: unity, streaming, streaming-assets

TL;DR: What approach should i use for streaming a maps assets?

My Unity project so far saves terrain meta data (in a flat file for now) and then streams the map as the player moves.

Upon completing this, it was clear that if I wanted to stream anything, its information would need to be stored somewhere.

With all this said, do I store my entire map's information in a local db or something?

For example, where object X must be, where objects C must be, etc etc. Instantiate everything at run time when that particular tile gets streamed.

This seems like a solution an inexperienced game dev (me) would come up with.

Comment: The method you describe sounds like it would work just fine. How have you tried implementing it so far? Did you run into any problems along the way, or any undesired outcomes? We can help you solve those issues if something isn't working the way you want, we just need more details about what's holding you back.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have not tried implementing it yet as my question pertains more to the theoretical side of thing. I can accomplish it comfortably, it just feels like there is a better solution. It seems almost pointless to store information unity holds(scene setup). Was wondering what techniques are used to stream scene information

Comment: Presumably you considered using the built-in LoadSceneAsync to load scene files in the background?

Comment: yes, but it seems like bad practice to make each tile(terrain chunk with all assets) into a scene? 
You have however reminded me of subscenes(which is part of unity ECS), I think i will look into that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You seem to be saying both "it seems like a bad idea to store in my own file something I could store in a scene" and also "it seems like a bad idea to store this data in a scene" - maybe we need to unpack a bit more what specifically this "seeming like a bad idea" entails from your perspective. Have you done any tests or measurements that demonstrate an unwanted consequence from either approach?

Comment: I am pretty bad at explaining myself, so let me put it this way.
1. creating a scene in unity's editor (good, visual way to create a scene)
2. Storing all the necessary data from that scene to be able to recreate it(seems redundant since this information is in the scene i just made)

I have never came across good content/solutions on world streaming in unity, So essentially I am asking if my solution(point 2) is valid or if there are better ways to do this as I am no expert in game architecture.

Comment: You're right that you can skip the redundancy of storing the scene data in your own file by just streaming the scene file itself. But then if you consider creating and storing this data in a scene file "good" then why does it "seem like bad practice" to load it from this format using the built-in scene streaming methods?

Comment: Because I would have to split up my game into thousands of "scenes" for loading/unloading. Hence it "seems" like bad practice, I have no idea if it actually is. I don't even know what to search for or read up on(am I even asking the right questions?)

Comment: Also, I would like to thank you for the assistance, really appreciate it. Big ups!!!

Comment: Is it the manual work of making these scenes that's of concern? If so, you could edit your question to ask "How do I divide up my world for streaming without manually creating separate scene files?" or something similar. Or if that's not it, can you define more specially what "seems like bad practice" about it? Try to avoid words like "seem" or "bad" and focus on what specific outcome you want to avoid, or what specific aspect you want to improve.